# Onsen UI - Delete tabbar on new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

I'm working on a App with a login process.

My first page is the `index.html`

```
 <body ng-controller="AppController">
        <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
        <ons-tabbar var="menu">
            <ons-tab page="login.html" label="Home" icon="ion-home" active="true"></ons-tab>
            <ons-tab page="register.html" label="Über uns" icon="ion-ios-cog"></ons-tab>
        </ons-tabbar>
        <ons-template id="login.html">
            <ons-navigator animation="slide" var="app.navi">
                <ons-page ng-controller="PageController">
                  <ons-toolbar>
                    <div class="center">Anmelden</div>
                  </ons-toolbar>
                    <div class="login-form">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="loginEmail" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="E-Mail" value="">
                        <input type="password" ng-model="loginPassword" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="Passwort" value="">
                        <br><br>
                        <ons-button modifier="large" ng-click="login()" class="login-button">Anmelden</ons-button>
                        <br><br>
                        <ons-button modifier="quiet" ng-click="app.navi.pushPage('register.html');" class="register">Noch kein Mitglied ?</ons-button>
                        <ons-button modifier="quiet" ng-click="app.navi.pushPage('lostpasswort.html');" class="forgot-password">Passwort vergessen ?</ons-button>
                    </div>
                </ons-page>
            </ons-navigator>
        </ons-template>
        <ons-template id="register.html">
            <ons-page>
              <ons-toolbar>
                <div class="left"><ons-back-button>Zurück</ons-back-button></div>
                <div class="center">Registrieren</div>
              </ons-toolbar>

                <div class="login-form">
                    <input type="text" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="Vorname" value="">
                    <input type="text" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="Nachname" value="">
                    <input type="email" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="E-Mail" value="">
                    <input type="password" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="Passwort" value="">
                    <input type="password" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="Passwort bestätigen" value="">
                    <br><br>
                    <ons-button modifier="large" class="login-button">Registrieren</ons-button>
                </div>
            </ons-page>
        </ons-template>
        <ons-template id="lostpasswort.html">
            <ons-page>
              <ons-toolbar>
                <div class="left"><ons-back-button>Zurück</ons-back-button></div>
                <div class="center">Registrieren</div>
              </ons-toolbar>

                <div class="login-form">
                    <input type="email" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="E-Mail" value="">
                    <br><br>
                    <ons-button modifier="large" class="login-button">Neues Passwort senden</ons-button>
                </div>
            </ons-page>
        </ons-template>


        <ons-template id="about.html">
          <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="center">Über uns</div>
          </ons-toolbar>
          <ons-page>
            <p style="padding-top: 100px; color: #999; text-align: center">Page Contents</p>
          </ons-page>
        </ons-template>
    </body>
```

After the login succeed I want to change the page `(main.html)`. This works, but the tab bar from the `index.html` is also displayed in the new page.

How can I delete the old tabbar and set a new one in the new page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think u can use `ng-if`. After login your from your action you send a viewbag flag and then use ng-if to which tab bar u wanted to see or not. `

```
<div class="tabbable tabs-left" role="tabpanel" ng-if="'@ViewBag.tabId'=='p'">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
       <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#a" aria-controls="a" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Basic</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

`

Answer (score -1):

Basically if you want to navigate to a page without the tabbar then the tabbar should be inside the navigator, not the other way around.

```
<ons-navigator animation="slide" var="app.navi">
    <ons-tabbar var="menu">
        <ons-tab page="login.html" label="Home" icon="ion-home" active="true"></ons-tab>
        <ons-tab page="register.html" label="Über uns" icon="ion-ios-cog"></ons-tab>
    </ons-tabbar>
</ons-navigator>
```

The way things currently are the navigator is actually inside the login, making the navigation somewhat strange. 
If the user clicks the register tab then he will just go to that tab, but if he clicks the register button then he will still be in the login tab, but the contents of the tab will have changed. Also in one case he will see a slide animation and in the other it will just change the content.

Maybe it will be better if you choose only one way of navigating to a specific page.

- If you use tabs then you can use the methods `loadPage` and `setActiveTab` from the tabbar for the auth pages. For the other pages afterwards you can use the methods of the navigator.
- If you like to use navigators then maybe you could have nested navigators. One for main navigation and one for auth pages (you could have an `auth.html` loaded in the main navigator and have another navigator inside `auth.html`).
- Finally you could simplify things even more if you just remove the tabbar and have only one navigator. That will probably be easiest to navigate.

Also if you think that none of these options seem good enough and you have a better idea about how it would be easiest to do then feel free to [write a feature request at the onsenui repo](https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/issues/new).